# Installing PHP plugin in Intellij Idea Community Addition

Tags: php, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am trying to install PHP plugin in my Intellij Idea IDE (Community Edition version 14), I believe this is very much supported, as I see there's a plugin site showing community PHP plugin.

URL : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610?pr=idea_ce

have downloaded and trying to install from option Settings > plugin > "install plugin from disk..."

when I am selecting the above downloaded plugin it is showing error

"Plugin PHP is incompatible with this installation"

can someone please help.

-- Manish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the "Ultimate Edition" to use the PHP plugin, it will not work with the free Community Edition. See: [*IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

If you [click through for details on that plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/update/index?pr=idea_ce&updateId=21712) notice the strike-through on <del>Community Edition</del> under "Supported products".