# what is the URL for JetBrains IDE plug-in repository?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, repository

I thought this was a simple question, and still nothing works.

My first use-case is that the IDEA 15 (*Community*) appears to NOT have a repository configured.  The *Plugins" tab in the ***Settings*** window / dialogue supports three operation aside from clicking on a plugin.:

- A button for [`Install JetBrains plugins`] ... This seems to be things downloaded with the installer or updates;
- A [`Browse repositories plugins`] button ... which contains an "*empty*" list 
  Further this dialogue contains two buttons for:

  - A [`Manage repositories`]
  - [`HTTP proxy settings`] - Proxy configuration / setup
- An [`Install plugins from disk`] button ... which does what it says ;-)

This question to ask is, what URL do I need to put into that: 
*  The [`Manage repositories`]

... list because the clean install had "*nada*" in that list.

The list of JetBrains plugins isn't the same as the list on the plugins repository web page:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/

In fact IDEA help pages recommend using the JetBrains repository... They do not seem to want to let one know the URL.

Also, what is the "Community" plugins URL?  At the very least I'd like to verify that/*IF* the JetBrains plugin-list is updating (as there's no "update list" option to be seen).

Weird huh?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Many of the plugins browsable at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/ don't appear in my plugins list in IDEA. I think it might be because I'm using the Community Edition. If that's the case, I'm fine with it, I just would like it to be made clearer. Edit: Yes, confirmed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236351/installing-php-plugin-in-intellij-idea-community-addition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Manage repositories`] list should be empty, unless you have some private plugins repository.

A [`Browse repositories plugins`] button should show you all the plugins, if not then check your firewall or proxy settings, or click on the Reload button.

[[image: reload button[1]]

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem while using the Community edition and trying to install the lombok plugin. Setting the HTTP Proxy to "Auto-detect proxy settings" resolved it for me.

It's under browse repositories -> HTTP Proxy Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Auto detect proxy settings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the specific URL, either, but Meo's answer is correct in saying that there's no need to add it manually. It sounds like you're confused by the difference between the list you see on the site and the list you see in IDEA CE.

The reason for the difference isn't a missing URL at all, but rather that many of the plugins listed on the site are not enabled for the Community Edition, so it doesn't display them. The PHP plugin at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610 is an example. While that page doesn't make it clear that it requires the Ultimate Edition, you can find out by scrolling down to the Updates list and clicking the (latest) version number. There you'll find a Supported Products list, where the Community Edition is listed as being incompatible because the plugin requires the "ultimate" module (a module that is only included in IDEA Ultimate Edition).

[image: PHP Plugin Supported Products]

Comment: when a plugin shows in the list of 'available' plugins -- it is _allowed_ my that module.  You can look for various '_high-end_' plugins with community (say JRuby) it will not show in the list -- Result this question would not be posted

Comment: @will Sorry, I had difficulty parsing that. The above image, which is output specific to the PHP plugin, is saying that it has a dependency on the "com.intellij.modules.ultimate" modules, and that this module dependency is incompatible with the Community Edition. I think what I said is factually correct. Maybe you were trying to out the fact that I'm not actually answering the direct question "What is the URL?" by the OP, which is true. I lost sight of the question along the way. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `Browse Repositories...` is empty, perhaps something happened with your version of Android studio?

If you're on the Canary channel your build might be too advanced for plugins, for instance. At least, that's what I think my issue was, as I switched to another (older) instance and everything was fine after this

I felt a bit stupid upon realising this!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on my `Android Studio 3.6.1` but a quick restart after looking for solutions turned out to be the way to go.